# Find out field change after update in Symfony 2.x

Tags: symfony

I want to perform an action when a field changes from null to any value. 
`cat /tmp/tag.log` will only show `preupdate`. It continues to run without stopping.

This is what I have done.

```
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        if ($args->getEntity() instanceof Contact) {
           file_put_contents('/tmp/tag.log', 'preUpdate'  .PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

           if ($args->hasChangedField('assignedTo')){
              file_put_contents('/tmp/tag.log', 'preUpdate changed'  .PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
           }
           if ( $args->getOldValue('assignedTo') == null ){
              file_put_contents('/tmp/tag.log', 'preUpdate assignedTo is null '  .PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
           }
           if ( $args->getNewValue('assignedTo') != null) {
              file_put_contents('/tmp/tag.log', 'preUpdate changed  to :'.$args->getNewValue('assignedTo') . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
           }
        }
    }
```

I have registered this service with

```
          tags:
       - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

Comment: can you add more details on what you mean by "the code get stuck " ?

Comment: I have reworded my question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the field name. The correct field name is `user`. I use this `print_r(array_keys($args->getEntityChangeSet()))` to find out the correct field name.